# How to adjust the corner radius Windows Phoen 7 button?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I know that there is no property to set corner radius for Windows phone buttons. But my requirement is to create a button with curve edges. Can we write custom styles to create curved edge buttons..?..If so please tell me the link or any good tutorials..

Answer (score 2):

This may help You

```
<Button  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,636,0,0" Name="SignUpButton" VerticalAlignment="Top"   FontSize="18" Background="#6BA92A"
             Click="SignUpButton_Click">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="#6BA92A" Background="#6BA92A" CornerRadius="20,20,20,20" BorderThickness="2">
                    <Button   Content="Sign up "
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              Height="65"
                              Width="348"
                              FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                              BorderBrush="#6BA92A">
                    </Button>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is simple if you go to blend and edit the button template. But making more complex editing might want you to check this [link or tutorial](http://nirmitk26.blogspot.in/2011/02/round-button-in-windows-phone-7.html). Change the grid in the button template to border and then fix the corner radius to some value. This will make things quick.